# Why $\mathbb{P}(X > t) =_{t\to \infty} o(\frac{1}{t})$ for all random variable X?

Tags: probability

I found it in an exam but i didn't succeed in solving it...

Notice that we didn't assume that $X \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. For some random variables, this probably could goes to $0$ slower than $t^{-1}$ as $t\to\infty$. A random variable $X$ such that $\operatorname E|X|^{1/2}<\infty$ and $\operatorname E|X|^p=\infty$ for $p>1/2$ could be one example.

We have that
$$
\operatorname E|X|^r=r\int_0^\infty t^{r-1}P(|X|>t)dt
$$
for $r>0$. Set $r=3/4$. If $\operatorname E|X|^{3/4}=\infty$, we have that
$$
\frac34\int_0^\infty t^{-1/4}P(|X|>t)dt=\infty
$$
and $P(|X|>t)$ cannot be $o(t^{-1})$ as $t\to\infty$.